# GroupBy for consistently updated data

Tags: mongodb, group-by

Is there a package which makes updates on groupBy'ed data partially over the updated data points?

Suppose that I have a collection (say "CollectionA") on MongoDB, which is not fixed but updated on daily basis. This data has two keys, 'filedAt' and 'occurenceDate'. The first column is unique for each data. However, the second column may be a date long ago.

In such a case, I just want to make a new MongoDB collection, (say "CollectionB") which is the aggregation of CollectionA by GroupBy over 'occurrenceDate' key. Maybe I can do it by usual aggregation method like below;

```
db.CollectionA.aggregate( [
   {
      $group: { _id: "$occurenceDate", ... }
   }
] )
```

But since collectionA will grow daily, the time cost of executing the above method grows well. So, instead of doing this aggregation everyday, I just want to partial updates on each of the data points in CollectionA which is updated only.

My question is, is there a package which makes certain updates automatically? Or do I need to make a code for updating this by myself? If your package is not for MongoDB but for other data base python packages such as Pandas, it would be helpful for me.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried indexing the `occurrenceDate` column?

Comment: @ray What do you mean "indexing" the column?

Comment: Your description is suggesting a potential of unindexed grouping, which will be very slow when the collection grows. You can try [this official doc/guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/#create-an-index) to build an index first to see if it can help solving your issue.

Comment: @ray Thank you very much! I will read the guide first!